# $a_{n}=\frac{3n-1}{2n-1}$. Show that no product of the form $a_{n_1} a_{n_2} \dots a_{n_k}$ is a power of $2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let 
$$
  a_{n}=\dfrac{3n-1}{2n-1}.
$$

Show that any product of at least $2$ terms of this sequence is not a power of $2$.

In other words:

The equation
$$
  a_{n_1} a_{n_2} \cdots a_{n_k} = 2^a
$$ 
has no solutions where $a, n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$ are positive natural numbers and $k \geq 2$.

I know
$$
  \dfrac{3n-1}{2n-1}\equiv \dfrac{n-1}{-1}\equiv n-1\pmod 2 .
$$

Comment: What does "show that this sequence any product of a first term not powers of $2$"  mean?

Comment: @lulu,Now can you understand?

Comment: I think so, though $a_1=2$ is a counterexample.  Are you just excluding that one?

Comment: As a quick remark, no subscript $n$ with $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ can occur.  That's because, for such $n$, $2n-1\equiv 0\pmod 3$ so the denominator is divisible by $3$, and it is clearly not possible for the numerator to ever cancel that.